# How to make button perform action once

Tags: java, netbeans

I want a button to make a sound, but after just one click. But keeps playing again and again when clicked. How do I make the sound play once, then play again on the next page?

Here is the code:

```
Private void buttonMouseClicked
Audioinput audio =AudioStream.getAudioInputStream(this.get class().getResource ("/AppPackage/BH/chr.wav"));
Clip clip =AudioSystem.getClip();
clip.open(audio);
clip.start();
```

I just want to make sure noting happens when next this particular button is clicked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can put a global boolean variable and initially set it to false. When the mouse button is clicked, check first if the variable is false before continuing to play the audio. Do not proceed if the variable is true. If the variable is false, you can set it to true and then continue the code to start playing the audio.

```
boolean isPlaying = false;

private void buttonMouseClicked() {
    if (isPlaying) return;
    isPlaying = true;

    AudioInputStream audio;
    try {
        audio = AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(getClass().getResource("/AppPackage/BH/chr.wav"));
        Clip clip;
        clip = AudioSystem.getClip();
        clip.open(audio);
        clip.start();
    } catch (UnsupportedAudioFileException ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    } catch (LineUnavailableException ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }        
}
```

Maybe some part of your program has a code to detect if the audio has finished playing, you can set the variable back to false there so that you can play the audio again when you click the button.

Comment: Sorry can u do it more clearly, am using netbeans. Thanks

Comment: Thanks so much, what if am doing the samething for a score board, like each time a button is clicked, a score of 10 just be added, ones, but instead 10 is always added for same button wen clicked, here is the code

Comment: @chopsticks. I will gladly answer your question. But it seems that it's another topic. If you are fine with my answer to the current question above, please consider  accepting it. And then post another question and I will answer it.

Comment: String preval =Counter.get text+"";

Counter.setText("10")
Now this is for the first button clicked to set the first score of 10

Now this if for each correct answer.

Int d= Integer.parseInt(Counter.get text));

Int e=10;

Int f=d +10;
Counter.set text(f+ " ");

Now this keep adding ten again and again for each button. I want it to add 10 once for each button. Note Counter is a jLabel to display result.

Comment: Thanks @d_air, its stilling playing the sound if same button is clicked, maybe try adding the try and catch button so i can know were to place them

Comment: Yes I'm expecting that the sound will continue playing. The code above just prevents the program to start playing again the same sound when the button is pressed again while the previous sound has already started.

Comment: Do you want the sound to stop when you pressed the same button the second time?

Comment: Thanks, I will be waiting. I just want the audio to play and stop, and when that button is clicked, it will not play again.

Comment: The code above is already edited. This is what I'm expecting with the code above. When you clicked the button for the first time, the sound starts playing. When you click the button the second time, third time, fourth time and so on.., the sound will not be affected and continue to play until it finishes. After the sound stops playing and the button is clicked again multiples times, the sound will not play again.. Is this what you want? If not, please give additional information on what you want.

Answer (score 0):

For a button that you only want to act once, you can use setEnabled(false) after one action:

```
JButton myButton = new JButton("Only works once");
myButton.addActionListener(e -> {
    // Code for thing i only do once.
    // ...
    myButton.setEnabled(false);
});
```

For a JLabel I have to use a MouseListener instead of an ActionListener. The MouseAdapter is a MouseListener with methods I don't care about stubbed out. This means disabling it won't help and I need to add an extra variable to save the fact that it is already clicked.

```
JLabel myLabel = new JLabel("label you can click on once");
myLabel.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {

        boolean alreadyclicked = false;
        @Override
        public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
            if(!alreadyclicked) {
                // Code for doing stuff I only want to do once.
                alreadyclicked = true;
            }
        }
});
```

Comment: Am really sorry am the one not explaining this thing well, am using a jlabel, which variable name is B. So please how do I make it act once. Am sorry for this, please Dont get tired of explaining, it will help me along way.

Comment: Thanks the setEnabled(false) did the trick, but it stops me from going to the next page. I Dont know why. I just added it to the one button, but it also affected the next button,

Comment: Thanks so much @WillShackleford, am having error when I do the jlabel. Do I need to create a string? Pls can u explain all this. Thanks so much

Comment: Edit your question to paste the error in. You don't need to create a string. Jlabels can show text, or an icon or be empty.